# Number of terms of sequence under $n$ with no arithmetic bounds.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I mentioned to a friend recently the result that for any $n > 1$, there is an $N$ beyond which there is always a prime between $m$ and $nm$ (for $m>N$, if it wasn't clear).

They proclaimed "This is very intuitive, since by choosing a large enough $m$, the gap between $m$ and $nm$ will be also large and so with an infinite number of primes, it only makes sense that this would be the case." This heuristic makes sense for things like primes but I, not thinking this was intuitive in general, wondered if there were infinite sequences for which no such bounds exist...

Can you give examples of sequences where either:

a) $\exists n$ for which there is no $N$ satisfying the above criteria or preferably

b) $\nexists n$ for which there *is* an $N$ satisfying the above criteria?

I was thinking that at least a) could be shown for some doubly exponential sequences via generating function magic, but was not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the sequence of factorials? For any $n>1$, you reach a point where you have to multiply by a number greater than $n$ to get to the next factorial.

The condition you're looking at is, that after taking logarithms, terms occur within each interval of a given size. (This can be seen because $\log(mn)=\log(m)+\log(n)$, so every multiplication by $n$ just amounts to adding $\log(n)$.) However, even after taking logarithms, the distances between factorials grows without bound.

Comment: Thanks! (the factorial was sort of obvious!) However, I do not understand the logarithms point - why is the condition equivalent to the differences between logged terms being bounded?

Comment: I added a little more detail about that. Does it help?

Comment: Yes - of course! Thank you again.

Comment: A thought I had was what is the fastest growing sequence for which this is true? As in, you cannot bound the factorial function in the way above due to the logarithm bounding concept but you can do that for, say, $2n$.

It would have to be between the factorial and the exponentials (since they are bounded).

Comment: Well, when you take logs, exponential growth becomes arithmetic growth, i.e., equal gaps between terms, so anything faster than exponential outpaces that. If you want those gaps to grow without bound, then before logs, you need ratios of consecutive terms to grow without bound. Factorial growth is kind of an archetype for precisely that, but it’s easy to write down a sequence that grows ridiculously fast. I mean..... $n!^{n!}$ is pretty rapid growth!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how large a gap
you consider to be intuitive.

Wikipedia's article on prime gaps
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap)
has a number of interesting
results and conjectures
including this:

"In 1931, E. Westzynthius proved that maximal prime gaps grow more than logarithmically. That is,[9]

${\displaystyle \limsup _{n\to \infty }{\frac {g_{n}}{\log p_{n}}}=\infty .} 
$"